# Trying to scrape a website that requires login

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping

so i m new to this and been at it for almost a week now trying to scrape a website i use to collect analytics data (think of it like google analytics).
I tried playing around with xpath to figure out what this script is able to pull but all i get is "[]" as an output after running it.
Please help me find what i'm missing.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
#credentials
payload = {
    'username': '<my username>',
    'password': '<my password>',
    'csrf-token': '<auth token>'
}
#open a session with login
session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = '<my website>'
result = session_requests.get(login_url)

#passing the auth token

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath('//input[@name=\'form_token\']/@value')))[0]

result = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data=payload,
    headers=dict(referer=login_url)
)
#scrape the analytics dashboard from this event link
url = '<my analytics webpage url>'
result = session_requests.get(
    url,
    headers=dict(referer=url)
)
#print output using xpath to find and load what i need
trees = html.fromstring(result.content)
bucket_names = trees.xpath("//*[@id='statistics_dashboard']/div[1]/text()")

print(bucket_names)

print(result.ok)
print(result.status_code)
```

..........
this is what i get as a result

```
[]
True
200
```

Process finished with exit code 0

which is a big step for me because i've been getting so many errors to get to this point.